# Is there a way to use loops to better this code?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object

I'm essentially trying to find a better way to write this code using loops. Rational and Matrix are classes that I made. To make a Matrix object I need four Rational objects.

```java
       Rational r1 = r.multiplyValue(array[0][0]);
       Rational r2 = r.multiplyValue(array[0][1]);
       Rational r3 = r.multiplyValue(array[1][0]);
       Rational r4 = r.multiplyValue(array[1][1]);

       return new Matrix(r1,r2,r3,r4);
```

Comment: What is wrong with current code? What you mean by "better"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you have a `Matrix` constructor as such

```
public Matrix(Rational...rationals){
    // TODO: initialize stuff
}
```

then you could iterate through the array and contruct the `Matrix` object like this

```
    int[][] array = // Something useful

    Rational[] rs = new Rational[4];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
        rs[i*2+j] = r.multipleValue(array[i][j]);
      }
    }

    return new Matrix(rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can do that but you must be using some collection or data structure that stores homogeneous objects e.g. list or array.

Example below:

```
       List<Rational> list  = new ArrayList<>();

       for(int i=0;i<=1;i++){
       for(int j=0;i<=1;j++){
           list.add(r.multiplyValue(array[i][j]));
       }

       }


       return new Matrix(list); // modify constructor to accept list
```